# Clone order with products is carrying over order start and end dates to new order

Tags: configuration, order

We have an integrated solution with Salesforce and an internal solution that relies on the Order Start and End date on the apparent New Order page.

It is currently loading too much information from the previous order when an order is cloned.

I know that we can request our users make sure that field is populated with the correct data, but I would like to be able to make that field empty on clone instead of just asking them do so.

I cannot find this page anywhere within the Customize tab in Setup.

Do you know how to find this page to edit it or override it with Visualforce?

If using VisualForce, is there a way to obtain the current Apex code of a prebuilt Salesforce page to base my new VisualForce page on?

[image: Order page contaning Clone with Products button]
[image: Edit Order page showing the prepopulated data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a Quick Action to do this.  It would work for Salesforce1, and you've already got chatter enabled.

You can set the fields that you want to be 'cloned' as predefined fields.  And you can add in any other fields that need input onto the layout.  Your 'cloned' or 'predefined' fields don't even need to be visible!

You would use a Record Create action on your Order Object.

If you need to do a Clone with Products, then you'll need to setup a Flow that captures the products and then adds them into your new Order as well... this is a pretty cool combined use-case of the two.  The Flow would be triggered on Create of the new Order from the Quick Action.

If you like this idea, let me know and I can provide some insight into how it would look on the Flow side as well... but no need diving into specifics if you aren't interested in that solution option!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm researching your idea now, it seems to be a pretty interesting method of doing so. I'm reading this page (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm), would that be the first step?

Comment: So, I looked into your method and it definitely set me on the right path. The overall solution ended up being much simplier in my case, and doesn't really follow the path of fields and flows. Moderator: Should I accept his solution here and provide what I did differently in the comments, or go ahead and click "Answer Your Question?"

Comment: What did you decide to do?

Comment: I created a new button using the link path of the edit button and inserted variables into the URL that manipulated the form so that the data wasn't populated on the form. Using your reference to Quick Action, I found the Button, Links and Actions verbage, but there were no links for an Action on this page, only Buttons and Links.